# Is there a way to keep Custom Font Group active on Word-Ribbon in Restricted-Editing Mode?

Tags: vba, fonts, ms-word, styles, ribbon

I need to come up with a word template that works on Restricted-Editing to fix the styles but needs active buttons for Bold, Italics, Highlights, Underline, Alignment, etc. Is there a way to create a custom tab on the Word Ribbon that keeps the required group active? Currently, the font-group gets greyed out/disabled in Restricted-Editing mode.

Or is there any other way out to restrict users from adding new styles to the document while allowing them to use bold, italics, underline, highlight, etc. Any help will be of great help. Many thanks.
[image: Greyed out/disabled screenshot]

Comment: What would be the point of preventing the user from adding new styles to a document if you then allow the user access to all the formatting options that enables them to create new pseudo-styles by applying formatting directly? The whole point of this form of document protection is that it enables a defined set of formatting rules to be enforced.

Comment: Hi Timothy, thanks for joining. Yes, I understand the goal of enforcement is to set a fixed path but the participants/writers that I work with find it cumbersome to choose simple actions like bold/italics/highlights from the long list styles that we have. So, the aim is to restrict the writers from adding new styles yet keep the frequently used styles handy on the ribbon.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt does this answer to your question? The problem is the document gets messed up each time writers copy paste from other documents and as we come closer to the submission dates, formatting becomes a huge task especially with lengthy documents like 200 pages.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that but you can’t reuse Word’s font formatting controls, you have to write your own. This link can show you how to do that. https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/customize_ribbon_main.html

Comment: Hey @Rich, thank you very much for sharing this link. I will read it now.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to record macros and assign new symbol for each action via custom-ribbon option and this group remains active for use even in the restricted-editing mode.

But the new problem is the VBA screen is greyed out and I am not able to replace the built-in images with desired images.
Please help!

[image]

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it as a new question.